# Windows Server Administrator multiple directories

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

A windows server is used to process files and passes those files to s3 using a python script . [1] The python script uses a configuration file that is created during configuration at C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\s3cmd.ini .

The machine ran out of hard drive space, and since then the s3 script had stopped working. The configuration script could not be found - which was the cause, but from command prompt I ran configure again and it created a new config script which was placed in :\Documents and Settings\Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.022.

What are those directories?

So will I have to reconfigure the server randomly? In C:\Documents and Settings\ I see there are many of these directories... for example:

```
09/09/2010  10:51 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.011
09/09/2010  10:51 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.012
09/09/2010  10:52 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.013
09/09/2010  10:52 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.014
09/09/2010  10:52 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.015
09/09/2010  10:53 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.016
09/09/2010  10:53 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.017
09/09/2010  10:53 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.018
09/09/2010  10:54 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.019
09/09/2010  10:54 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.020
09/09/2010  10:54 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.021
09/09/2010  10:56 AM              Administrator.IP-0AF8D5C1.022
```

Is a new one created everytime I log-in?  Any ideas what happened?

[1] - http://s3tools.org/s3cmd